# How to add custom color to a shape made with core graphics?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I have made a shape with core graphics and I want to fill it with a custom color. For example instead of default red i want dark red.

This is the code for the shape and color:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)


CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 130)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 180, 100)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 60)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 50)

CGContextStrokePath(context)

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(context)
}
```

Comment: Sounds great. What's the problem?

Comment: How do you add a custom color to a shape? I only know how to use the basic colors like : redColor() purpleColor() and all those

Comment: Gotcha. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try reading the docs and solve things yourself. You are saying:

```
UIColor.redColor()
```

If that isn't the color you want, make a different color, by calling

```
UIColor(red:r, green:g, blue:b, alpha:a)
```

...where `r`, `g`, `b`, and `a` are CGFloat values.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just needed to get on the right track ;D